# Mysql syntax error in java

Tags: java, mysql, sql, syntax-error

i'm pretty sure that my query is correct but i get the message " you have an error in your sql syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySql server version for the right syntax near to 'group='aaa' and Date_de_naissanse........." at line 1 .
i checked the syntax meany times i did it in two versions but still the same  message . here's my code :

```
  if (rdps==true){
  con = connection.connect();
  String sql ="SELECT * FROM eleve_ps WHERE Nom_et_prenom=? and Group=? and Date_de_naissanse=? and Responsable=? and CIN=? and Telephone=? and Adresse=?";

        try{

        st=con.prepareStatement(sql);
        st.setString(1, txtnp.getText());
        st.setString(2, txtg.getText());
        st.setInt(6, Integer.parseInt(txtt.getText()));
        st.setString(4, txtr.getText());
        st.setString(5, txtc.getText());
        st.setDate(3, date);
        st.setString(7, txta.getText());
        rs=st.executeQuery();
        if(rs.next()){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"VOTRE COURRIER DEJA EXISTE");
        }else{
          String insert = "INSERT INTO `eleve_ms`(`ID`, `Nom_et_prenom`, `Group`, `Date_de_naissanse`, `Responsable`, `CIN`, `Telephone`, `Adresse`) VALUES (Null,'"+txtnp.getText()+"','"+txtg.getText()+"','"+date+"','"+txtr.getText()+"','"+txtc.getText()+"','"+Integer.parseInt(txtt.getText())+"','"+txta.getText()+"')";
            try{
                st=con.prepareStatement(insert);
                st.executeUpdate();
                this.setVisible(false);
            }
            catch(Exception e ){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,e);
            }
        }

        }
        catch(Exception e){
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,e); 
        }
        rdms=false;
  }
```

and so is this version :

```
if (rdps==true){
        con = connection.connect();
        String sql ="SELECT * FROM eleve_ps WHERE Nom_et_prenom='"+txtnp.getText()+"' and Group='"+txtg.getText()+"' and Date_de_naissanse='"+date+"' and Responsable='"+txtr.getText()+"' and CIN='"+txtc.getText()+"' and Telephone='"+Integer.parseInt(txtt.getText())+"' and Adresse='"+txta.getText()+"' ";
        try{      
        st=con.prepareStatement(sql);
        rs=st.executeQuery();
        if(rs.next()){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"VOTRE COURRIER DEJA EXISTE");
        }else{
            String insert = "INSERT INTO `eleve_ps`(`ID`, `Nom_et_prenom`, `Group`, `Date_de_naissanse`, `Responsable`, `CIN`, `Telephone`, `Adresse`) VALUES (Null,'"+txtnp.getText()+"','"+txtg.getText()+"','"+date+"','"+txtr.getText()+"','"+txtc.getText()+"','"+Integer.parseInt(txtt.getText())+"','"+txta.getText()+"')";
            try{
                st=con.prepareStatement(insert);
                st.executeUpdate();
                this.setVisible(false);
            }
            catch(Exception e ){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,e);
            }
        }

        }
        catch(Exception e){
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,e); 
        }

  }
```

Comment: Group is a reserved word in SQL Syntax (Group By). Try to put the name into backticks like you did in the insert statement.

Comment: you need 'eleve_ms' and not ` around eleve_ms (quotes).

Comment: Why use a prepared statement if you paste the same raw data straight into the next query?

Comment: Completely off-topic, but shouldn't it be "Votre courrier existe déjà" rather than "Votre courrier déjà existe"?

Comment: Please read about SQL injection and on how PrepareStatemet and `?` are meant to be used: your code is vulnerable to SQL injection.

Comment: My bad: you actually know about how to use prepared statements (your `select` is ok) - why don't you use it properly in the `insert` too?

Comment: @Mena i just did anything there to test the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in comments: `GROUP` is a reserved word and MySQL is case insensitive.

Try this, paying attention to the back ticks surrounding the word `Group`.

```
String sql ="SELECT * FROM eleve_ps WHERE Nom_et_prenom=? and `Group`=? and Date_de_naissanse=? and Responsable=? and CIN=? and Telephone=? and Adresse=?";
```

Comment: And, try to avoid table names like `GROUP`, `SELECT`, `WHERE`, and the like.